# How to post a custom form in WordPress based website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I've developed a form using raw HTML code as well as referenced inside separate CSS and javascript code files. Now, what I would like to do is to create a custom form in WordPress based on my raw HTML, CSS and javascript files. I am not sure which approach would make the most sense. The form is also supposed to send an email containing user-filled form fields. Is there any standard WordPress approach to achieve it? Should I create a custom plugin or perhaps use the already existing one? I found few which seem to enable certain custom codes (eg. HTML Forms, Insert Html Snippet, Raw HTML) but do they really? The number of options is really overwhelming and I am not convinced to any of them.

I am sure some of you dealt with something like that before, is it personal experience or helping out someone in a similar case. Hopefully, you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, You can but for this, you need to write code first. First you should google it.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/283965/how-do-i-send-mail-with-custom-form-data-using-wordpress

Comment: Questions asking us to decide which method or methods are appropriate solutions to your business case are purely subjective.  Questions that are meant to solely solicit opinions are off-topic for SO and should be closed.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @GufranHasan Thanks, Ive seen this before. Was not sure it fits here.

Comment: @JustinR. It's not about opinions but facts. If asking for a "working" solution while I have completely no idea how to proceed is a subjective question then I apologize. I wanted to avoid pointless attempts that would not even achieve the desired effect. Seems my question was misunderstood.